# Using signature of another apk

Tags: android, signing

I'm not sure whether this question is valid here or not but i saw one android app using another android app's signature. Both apks are not from the same developer but the signatures are same. Because i can update first apk with second apk and it shows signatures are same. There's no chance that the first apk is made by the same developer because i'm talking about a famous android app here. Even the manifest files are different. For some reasons, i can't give link to first apk. Any guess how the first apk got same signature?

Comment: Same CN or same fingerprint?

Comment: what do you mean `you can update first apk with second apk`?

Comment: @born: yes. same fingerprint

Comment: @murat: what i mean is that, i installed 1st apk and then updated it with second apk(which is from the real developer) and the first apk got updated. That means both apks are using same signature otherwise it'll give a conflicting signature error.

Comment: one thing to be noted here is that the 1st apk is not supposed to work. it won't work like the real app, it'll force close. But that's not the issue here. I'm wondering how the 1st apk got same signature? I tried to decompile some open source apk, recompiled it and copied original signatures. But upon install, i'm getting error in logcat "no signature" for classes.dex. Then how this apk got same signature even with many changes in manifest file.

Comment: they must have been signed with the same key. there is no other way.

Comment: that's unbelievable for me muratgu. Because I'm talking about facebook here

Comment: only possibility i see is that, parts of original apk is edited out, and copied same signature. But the manifest file contains some other app's package name etc. That's why i cant believe that real apk is edited and signature copied. Also, copying original signature is not working for me.

Comment: how are you certain that the first (or second) apk is authentic?

Comment: First apk is not authentic. but second apk is authentic(apk from google play). That's why i said 1st apk is not supposed to work like real apk. It serves some other purpose. first apk is not from facebook for sure.